# Count query for a table joined twice referenced to by different foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Let's assume I have two tables:

```
Users
id: integer
name: string

Messages
id: integer
sender_id: integer
receiver_id: integer
body: string
```

I need to get stats of sent and received messages for all users.

For sent messages my query works as expected:

```
SELECT users.id, COUNT(*) total_sent 
FROM users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN messages sent_messages ON sent_messages.sender_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id;

+----+------------+
| id | total_sent |
+----+------------+
|  1 |          3 |
|  2 |          2 |
|  3 |          1 |
+----+------------+
```

However I need to expand the query and get count of received messages at the same time. My attempt was:

```
SELECT users.id, COUNT(sent_messages.id) total_sent, COUNT(received_messages.id) total_received
FROM users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN messages sent_messages ON sent_messages.sender_id = users.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN messages received_messages ON received_messages.receiver_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id;
```

Unfortunately, it produces wrong results.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Try COUNT(distinct sent_messages.id) and COUNT(distinct received_messages.id).

Comment: @jarlh - it did the job :) thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count distinct `receiver_id` for total sent messages and distinct `sender_id` for received messages

```
SELECT u.id, COUNT(distinct s.receiver_id) total_sent, 
COUNT(distinct r.sender_id) total_received
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN messages s ON s.sender_id = u.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN messages r ON r.receiver_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7342/2)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you:

`select u.id, r.total_received, s.total_sent from users as u 
left outer join 
(select count(id) as total_received, receiver_id from Messages group by receiver_id ) as r on r.receiver_id =u.id
left outer join 
(select count(id) as total_sent, sender_id from Messages group by sender_id) as s on sender_id=u.id`